# Ionic 2 DatetimePicker with format [DDD MMM D|Today] h:mm A

Tags: datetime, typescript, ionic-framework, datepicker, ionic2

I would like to create this type of datetime picker with the format like I have in the [image]picture ([DDD MMM D|Today] h:mm A ) by using Ionic 2 ion-datetime directive.

Comment: Did you come up with a solution ?

Comment: Yes. I suggest using the Ionic Native Plugin - Date Picker - https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/date-picker/

Comment: Thx, will have a look at it !